# Angular: Unable to fetch router events

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to get the previous route from a component. But when I route to that component, my code for router events subscription isn't working. When I leave the component, it works. Even when I leave, I'm unable to fetch the event of type `NavigationEnd`. Please take a look at my code.

In router config:

```
{
    path: 'transactions',
    component: TransactionsComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateAuthGuardService],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ViewTransactionsComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'my-transactions',
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {
            path: 'my-transactions',
            component: MyTransactionsComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'transactions-pending-my-approval',
            component: PendingTransactionsComponent
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'transaction-details',
        component: TransactionDetailsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'create-transaction',
        component: CreateTransactionComponent,
        data: { title: 'Create Transaction' }
      },
      {
        path: 'edit-transaction/:name',
        component: CreateTransactionComponent,
        data: { title: 'Edit Transaction' }
      }
    ]
  }
```

In `CreateTransactionComponent`:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.transactionService.getDynamicTableData().then(categories => {
      this.categories = categories;
    });

    this.dataSubscription = this.route.data.subscribe(data => this.title = data.title);
    this.routeParamsSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.name = params.name);
    this.eventSubscription = this.router.events
      .subscribe(event => {
        console.log(event); //not working when I enter this component but works when I leave
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.routeParamsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.eventSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more unclear to me

Comment: It's also unclear to me what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: As per my code, If I navigate to the path `create-transaction`, the `CreateTransactionComponent` is invoked and should execute the `console.log` within the ngOnInit() function, right? But it's not happening. When I navigate to (enter) that page, I see nothing in the console. But when I navigate to some other page, that `console.log` is getting executed and I see the output. My question is, why is it not working when I enter the page as it is supposed to?

Comment: Ultimately, I want to get the previous route (from which page I reached this page).